# Writing to routing socket: not in table, Why?

Tags: macos, iterm

```
▶ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.100.1      UGScI          15        0     en0
10.9.4/24          link#4             UCS             1        0     en5
10.9.4.26/32       link#4             UCS             1        0     en5
10.9.4.254/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en5
10.9.4.254         0:d:66:2c:3e:40    UHLWIr          0        0     en5   1177
10.9.4.255         ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2     en5
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3  1656505     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en5
169.254            link#5             UCSI            0        0     en0
192.168.100/23     link#5             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.100.1/32   link#5             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.100.1      0:8:e3:ff:fc:4     UHLWIir        17       14     en0   1177
192.168.100.83/32  link#5             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.101.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2     en0

▶ route -n get default
route: writing to routing socket: not in table
```

Why am I getting an error in that last command?